# Is it possible to change key shortcuts in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Is it possible to change the shortcut for "Execute Selection in Console" from <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, similarly to RStudio?

Answer (score 14):

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Keymap`. You should be able to see something similar to this:

[image]

You can remove the current shortcut key, and add a new one.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can also set the shortcut settings of an IDE you are used to. For instance, I'm used to using eclipse so I switched to eclipse.

Comment: You can add plugins for VSCode or Visual Studio and activate them in the keymap. Easier than manually defining them all!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to keymap in Settings , right click u will have option like add keyboard shortcut and add mouse shortcut.